# Calculate 2 dataframes with related elements but different shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

main_df

| ID | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 02 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 03 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 04 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

sub_df

| ID | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 02 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 04 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I want to add sub_df onto main_df, and substitute all values greater than 1 into 1 ( all elements in main_df should only contains 0 and 1s)

The final result should look like this:

| ID | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 02 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 03 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 04 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I've tried append(), merge() but the result will only append the dataframe.
I will have to write another python function to loop through dataframe to calculate.
Is there a better way to complete the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.add` with `fill_value==0`.

Set `ID`s as index if they are not already so:

```
df1 = df1.set_index("ID")
df2 = df2.set_index("ID")
```

`pandas` will fill any hole with `fill_value` when comparing indices to each other.

```
new_df = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

Then use `astype` to convert it to either zero or one.

Note that this is bit hacky if you were to have decimals.

```
print(new_df.astype(bool).astype(int))
```

Or just plain old comparison *without conversion to int*:

```
new_df.mask(new_df.gt(1), 1)
```

Output:

```
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G
ID                     
1   1  1  0  0  1  0  0
2   0  0  1  1  0  1  1
3   1  0  1  0  0  0  0
4   1  1  0  1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `concat` and `groupby.max`:

```
>>> pd.concat([main_df, sub_df]).groupby('ID', as_index=False).max()
   ID    A  B  C  D  E    F    G
0   1  1.0  1  0  0  1  0.0  0.0
1   2  0.0  0  1  1  0  1.0  1.0
2   3  1.0  0  1  0  0  0.0  0.0
3   4  1.0  1  0  1  0  0.0  0.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

both dataframe: set id as index

```
main_df.loc[sub_df.index, sub_df.columns] = sub_df
print(main_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, works only with 0/1. Add df2 to df1, fillna, add again df1 and clip to 1:

```
df1.add(df2).fillna(0, downcast='infer').add(df1).clip(upper=1)
```

output:

```
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G
ID                     
1   1  1  0  0  1  0  0
2   0  0  1  1  0  1  1
3   1  0  1  0  0  0  0
4   1  1  0  1  0  0  0
```